Finding out the number of minima for a fourier expansion
Suppose I have a Fourier series f(x) = $\sum_{n=1}^N t_n \cos(nx)$ defined in the domain $(-\pi,\pi]$.
we need to prove that mathematically we can ' at most' have N minima points excluding the boundary region of the domain for some $\{t_n\}$.
Note we can only consider points $x \in (-\pi,\pi)$

this is the plot of $f(x) = t_1 \cos x + t_2 \cos 2x$. We are getting 2 minima for $\{t_i\}$ = {-1.6,2.6}.
